# How to remove a file from a commit which is not the most recent using eclipse when their are multiple commits to be pushed

Tags: eclipse, git, github, git-commit

I have a file which is >100MB which I have committed and pushed to my local repo but when I attempt to push several commits to the remote through eclipse (this is how I've always done it) I am given the following error:

Repository https://github.com/tjd45/PartIIProject.git

pre-receive hook declined
error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
error: Trace: 340348513f636af28e13a860a95b4a7e
error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
error: File Part II Project/TenMoves.arff is 103.85 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

I would like to know if there is anyway of deleting this file (TenMoves.arff) from the commit despite the fact that it is the 4th most recent commit and not the most recent. And if not, if there is anyway of configuring git-lfs with eclipse in order to get around the problem.

I am not that comfortable using git so if I have fundamentally misunderstood anything I apologise and if you require any further information please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To completely remove a  file existence from al the commits below command is useful.

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch <file>'
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this sorted the problem eventually, had to mess around with a bit of git pull too as it made it think the local was behind, but got success in the end.